# I set socket as a Object class, how i can call it in another fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, socket.io

The project that i handle has set socket as a object class named SocketService.kt. and i want to call socket emit on another class. how i can do that?

```
object SocketService {

    var TAG = SocketService::class.java.simpleName


    fun init() {

        var opts = IO.Options()
        opts.query = "token="+RushOwlApp.getApp().getUserToken()

        var socket = IO.socket(RushOwlApp.getApp().getAppMetaData()?.socketUrl,opts)
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Socket Connected")
            socket.emit("hello")
        }.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Socket on Disconnect")
            socket.connect()
        }.on("helloResponse"){( args ) ->
            Log.i(TAG,args.toString())
        }

        socket.connect()

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If some class marked as `object` in Kotlin you can refer to its properties and methods through the class name. In your case it will look like this:

```
// Call it from wherever you want
SocketService.init()
```

Comment: and how if i want to emit?

Comment: what do you want to emit?

Comment: emit an event on another class